# Meteor - Why does the web app show loading forever, and WebSockets says pending

Tags: javascript, meteor, websocket

I'm new to meteor and I just deployed my first test app. The problem I'm having is with the deployed app, when I visit the site, the FavIcon image in Google Chrome for example, always shows loading.

When I go to the network tab in the debugger, it shows WebSockets is pending.

[image: loading bar]

[image: debugger]

I don't know if its OCD or what, but it's really annoying seeing that go in circles forever and ever. This is also one of my first times dealing with WebSockets, so I don't know if this kind of behaviour is normal or what. Any information would be great thanks.

Comment: you might want to use chrome's networking tab to profile how files load and when the ws connection is established

Comment: I assume you're just test deploying on *****.meteor.com? Could you post your app code?

Comment: Yeah that is not normal behavior. You have a unintended recursion happening somewhere within your code. Post some of your code. Check your browser console for any errors. Insert some console.log statements in various places throughout your codebase to try and pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with favicon rendering on localhost but not when I deployed to meteor.com.  From memory, I had to change the URL of the favicon to include an extra "/" at the front.  In my case, my graphic assets are in folder 'public/art/' and I had to change the line in 'head' to read:

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 64x64" href="/art/favicon.ico">
```